# Dynamic call of function with optional args

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I need to process a lot of requests using Requests library on Python 3.

I added a level of abstraction by using my own class which will manage Requests call.

```
def requests(self, method, domain, url, parameters, token):
    if method == 'GET':
        r = Requests.get(domain + url, params=parameters, timeout=self.timeout)
    if method == 'POST':
        r = Requests.post(domain + url, params=parameters, timeout=self.timeout)
```

I find it quite too verbose to do a if for each kind of requests, knowing that I'll will add others if about authentication, specific headers and so on. (adding others args as `auth=MyAuth(log, pwd)`, and so on)

Is there any way to dynamically call a function ? Something like :

```
d = dict()
d['parameters'] = parameters
d['token'] = token
r  = Requests.(method)(d)
```

Regards.

Comment: [`requests.request(**d)`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request)? (Assuming `d` also includes `method` and `url` keys.)

Comment: I use this for my own class.

But Requests refered to a Python library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). I can't handle it like this, no ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's relevent. Maybe I just don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Requests offers a wide variety of functionalities. However, I need a way to call them dynamically, with dynamic arguments.

Comment: @glibdud, my bad, I didn't not understand the way you mean it !

I thought you were asking to create a function this way. Little did I know you can call a function using ** too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @glibdud said, you can use ** in function call too.

In my case, using `getattr(Requests, method.lower())(domain + url, **args)` did the trick. Where `args = {'params'=parameters,'timeout':self.timeout}` for example.

Comment: The naming convention is `*args` and `**kwargs`, so you should probably rename your variable `args` to `kwargs`to make it slightly easier to read.